Spring Boot: Check if ObjectMapper Module is Registered before Registration
In Spring Boot, I'm working with ObjectMapper and want to avoid registering a module (e.g., TextModule) if it's already registered. Is there a recommended approach to check for existing registration before calling registerModule?
ApplicationContext context = event.getApplicationContext();
TextModule module = (TextModule) context.getBean("textModule");
ObjectMapper mapper = ObjectMapper.getObjectMapper(); 

mapper.registerModule(module);


The ObjectMapper has getRegisteredModuleIds() method which returns the Set of registered modules id's. The moduleId is fully classified class name
[com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module, jackson-module-parameter-names, jackson-datatype-jsr310, org.springframework.boot.jackson.JsonMixinModule, org.springframework.boot.jackson.JsonComponentModule]


The set of Module typeIds that are registered in this ObjectMapper. By default the typeId for a module is it's full class name (see Module.getTypeId()).

So u can check if the x.x.TextModule exists in the Set and then register if it doesn't exists, and also as a recommended option i would suggest to use
IGNORE_DUPLICATE_MODULE_REGISTRATIONS to ignore the duplicate modules

Feature that determines whether multiple registrations of same module should be ignored or not; if enabled, only the first registration call results in module being called, and possible duplicate calls are silently ignored; if disabled, no checking is done and all registration calls are dispatched to module.


There is no such method for checking this, but you can allow or not duplicated registrations by setting
MapperFeature.IGNORE_DUPLICATE_MODULE_REGISTRATIONS

From documentation:
    /**
     * Feature that determines whether multiple registrations of same module
     * should be ignored or not; if enabled, only the first registration call
     * results in module being called, and possible duplicate calls are silently
     * ignored; if disabled, no checking is done and all registration calls are
     * dispatched to module.
     *<p>
     * Definition of "same module" is based on using {@link Module#getTypeId()};
     * modules with same non-null <code>type id</code> are considered same for
     * purposes of duplicate registration. This also avoids having to keep track
     * of actual module instances; only ids will be kept track of (and only if
     * this feature is enabled).
     *<p>
     * Feature is enabled by default.
     *
     * @since 2.5
     */
    IGNORE_DUPLICATE_MODULE_REGISTRATIONS(true)


Thanks, @Alex! I appreciate the tip.  This will definitely be helpful when I implement this
